# What is the best method to add error handling in SQL 2005 stored procs?

Tags: sql-server-2005, stored-procedures, best-practices

What’s a good way to make stored procs robust enough that they can scale very well and also contain error handling?

Additionally, whats the best way to handle multiple error scenarios in a stored proc and have an intelligent feedback system that will return meaningful error information to the calling apps?

Comment: Try using the newer TRY CATCH block in SQL Server 2005. http://www.sommarskog.se/error_handling_2005.html

Comment: Hi @Kacalapy ~ I'ld like to recommend in the future to ask each question in its own right and that way we can have specific answers focused on one question at a time. I encourage you to do that with this question.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Alex Kuznetsov has a great chapter in his book **Defensive Database Programming** (Chapter 8) that covers T-SQL TRY...CATCH, T-SQL transactions & SET XACT_ABORT settings, and using client-side error handling. It will help you a lot in deciding which of the options makes the most sense for what you need to accomplish.

It is available for ***free*** at [**this site**](http://www.red-gate.com/our-company/about/book-store/defensive-database-programming). I am in no way affiliated with the company, but I do own the hard copy version of that book.

There are a lot of little details on this subject that are explained very well by Alex.

*Per Nick's request... (but not all of this is in the chapter)*

In terms of scaling, you need to be brutally honest about which activities need to be in the db code and which should be in the app. Ever notice how fast-executing code tends to come back to designing for a single concern per method?

The easiest way to communicate would be custom error codes (> 50,000). It's also pretty fast. It does mean you'd have to keep the db code and app code in sync. With a custom error code, you can also return useful information in the error message string. Because you have an error code strictly for that situation, you can write a parser in the app code tailored to the error's data format.

Also, which error conditions need retry logic in the database? If you want to retry after X seconds, then you're better off handling that in the app code so the transaction doesn't block as much. If you are only re-submitting a DML operation right away, repeating it in the SP could be more efficient. Keep in mind, though, that you'll have to possibly duplicate code or add a layer of SPs to accomplish a retry.

Really, that's currently the biggest pain with TRY...CATCH logic in SQL Server at the moment. It can be done, but it's a bit of an oaf. Look for some improvements coming to this in SQL Server 2012, especially [re-throwing system exceptions](http://lennilobel.wordpress.com/2011/11/12/throwing-errors-in-sql-server-2012/) (preserving the original error number). Also, there's [FORMATMESSAGE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186788%28v=sql.110%29.aspx), which adds some flexibility in constructing error messages, especially for logging purposes.

Comment: Great advice and a very good book!

Comment: Red Gate offers several extremely helpful free E-books, and this one is certainly one of the better ones.  Great suggestion.

Comment: Not all of their books do this, but the free version of Kuznetsov's "Defensive..." book does not contain the last 2 chapters on Transaction Isolation Levels and Developing Modifications that survive concurrency. For me. the content in there was worth the purchase.

Answer (score 7):

This is our template (error logging removed)

Notes:

- Without XACT_ABORT, all TXN begin and commit/rollbacks must be paired
- A commit decrements @@TRANCOUNT
- A rollback returns @@TRANCOUNT to zero so you'd get error 266
- You can not ROLLBACK the current layer only (eg decrement @@TRANCOUNT on rollback)
- XACT_ABORT suppresses error 266
- Each stored proc must conform to the same template so each call is atomic
- The rollback check is actually redundant because of XACT_ABORT. However, it makes me feel better, looks odd without, and allows for situations where you don't want it on
- This allows for client side TXNs (like LINQ)
- [Remus Rusanu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/105929/remus-rusanu) has a [similar shell](http://rusanu.com/2009/06/11/exception-handling-and-nested-transactions/) that uses save points. I prefer an atomic DB call and don't use partial updates like their article

...so don't create more TXNs than you need

However,

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [Name]
AS
SET XACT_ABORT, NOCOUNT ON

DECLARE @starttrancount int

BEGIN TRY
    SELECT @starttrancount = @@TRANCOUNT

    IF @starttrancount = 0
        BEGIN TRANSACTION

       [...Perform work, call nested procedures...]

    IF @starttrancount = 0 
        COMMIT TRANSACTION
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    IF XACT_STATE() <> 0 AND @starttrancount = 0 
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
    RAISERROR [rethrow caught error using @ErrorNumber, @ErrorMessage, etc]
END CATCH
GO
```

Comment: what if @@TRANCOUNT is greater than 0? you dont do any work or have any feedback?

Comment: @kacalapy: there is no such thing as a nested transaction so we don't start another http://www.scribd.com/doc/49579859/33/Nested-Transactions-Are-Real

Answer (score 3):

I use Try/Catch, but I also gather as much information as possible and write that to an errorlog AFTER the rollback.  In this example, "LogEvent" is a stored procedure that writes to an EventLog table, containing the details of what happened.  GetErrorInfo() is a function call that returns the exact error message.

When an error occurs, the information is gathered, the procedure skips down to the error handling section and issues a rollback.  The information is written to the log, then the procedure exits.

Considering the extra procedure/function calls involved, it seems a little over the top.  HOWEVER this method is tremendously helpful when trying to debug the problem.

```
exec LogEvent @Process, @Database, 'Attempting to insert blah blah blah'
BEGIN TRY
  insert into MyTable
  select Values
    from MyOtherTable

  select @rowcount = @@ROWCOUNT
END TRY
-- ErrorHandling
BEGIN CATCH
  select @error          = ERROR_NUMBER(),
         @rowcount       = -1,
         @TableAction    = 'insert',
         @TableName      = @Database + '.MyTable',
         @AdditionalInfo = '(Attempting to insert blah blah blah) '  + dbo.GetErrorInfo()
   GOTO TableAccessError
END CATCH

.
.
.
.

TableAccessError:
IF (@@TRANCOUNT > 0) ROLLBACK
select @output = upper(@TableAction) + 
       ' ERROR - An error occurred while ' + 
       case (@TableAction)
         when 'update' then 'updating'
         when 'delete' then 'deleting'
         else @TableAction + 'ing'
       end + 
       ' records ' + 
       case(@TableAction) 
         when 'select' then 'from' 
         when 'update' then 'in' 
         when 'insert' then 'into'
         else 'from'   
         end  + 
         ' the ' + @TableName + ' table.'
select @output = @output + '  @@ERROR: '         + convert(varchar(8),@error) 
select @output = @output + '  @@ROWCOUNT: '      + convert(varchar(8),@rowcount) 

select @output = @output + isnull(@AdditionalInfo,'')
exec LogEvent @Process, @Database, @Output
RAISERROR(@output,16,1) with log
select @ReturnCode = -1
GOTO THE_EXIT
```