# Error handling in container procedures

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, stored-procedures, error-handling

I'm aware of and use the techniques in [this question.](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/2296/1945)

In my environment we have a lot of container procedures that call subprocedures, that may call other procedures, ad infinitum.

For me personally, I normally use `TRY/CATCH` in each level of the procedures.  This will sometimes result in multiple duplicate error messages but it's clear what happened and in what proc.

I have some coworkers who take a different approach.  Namely:
- Have each stored proc issue a return code
- Evaluate the return code for each stored proc after execution
- Raiserror in the outermost proc if a bad return code is received

I believe they do this so they can get the actual line number from the erroring procedure (instead of having it return the line number of the `RAISERROR` in the `CATCH` block).

To me this seems like it would be harder to implement and maintain, but I'm not an expert on SQL Server error handling, so I thought I would bring it up here.

**Is there any material advantage to either method for handling errors in container procedures?**

Comment: First off, great question +1.  I have to agree with you, just due to the fact that the owning procedure should be handling its own errors.  I don't see the benefit of shuffling that off to a calling proc.  For instance, if Proc A is called by Proc B, Proc B has to handle the return code from Proc A.  If Proc A is also called by Proc C, then Proc C has to handle the return code from Proc A.  It's duplicate the work, if instead you just had Proc A handle internal errors there.  Just my opinion.

Comment: @Shark I agree but the folks who did this aren't dummies so I'm thinking there is a reason for it that I'm just not seeing.

Comment: I prefer your approach, which is similar to what I have in the linked question: clear, obvious, easy to find out where the fan got the brown stuff on it

Answer (score 3):

I use this pattern proposed in [Exception Handling and Nexted Transactions](http://rusanu.com/2009/06/11/exception-handling-and-nested-transactions/):

```
create procedure [usp_my_procedure_name]
as
begin
    set nocount on;
    declare @trancount int;
    set @trancount = @@trancount;
    begin try
        if @trancount = 0
            begin transaction
        else
            save transaction usp_my_procedure_name;

        -- Do the actual work here

lbexit:
        if @trancount = 0   
            commit;
    end try
    begin catch
        declare @error int, @message varchar(4000), @xstate int;
        select @error = ERROR_NUMBER(), @message = ERROR_MESSAGE(), @xstate = XACT_STATE();
        if @xstate = -1
            rollback;
        if @xstate = 1 and @trancount = 0
            rollback
        if @xstate = 1 and @trancount > 0
            rollback transaction usp_my_procedure_name;

        raiserror ('usp_my_procedure_name: %d: %s', 16, 1, @error, @message) ;
    end catch   
end
```

This not only raises, but also can rollback to savepoint, if possible. This is very convenient in batch processing, the batch is not lost if a row has an error.

I never ever use return codes in stored procs. Returns codes beg to be ignored. I acknowledge the problem of nested errors as an annoyance, but with SQL Serevr 2012 you have the simple [`THROW;`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee677615.aspx) (no other arguments) to re-raise the original exception.

Answer (score 0):

I use a mix of both.  I use Try/Catch whenever I am performing an insert/update/delete, or even if I am doing a critical select (e.g. one that absolutely must return data, or a select from a remote dataset)

In each stored procedure I have an error handling section that calls a function called GetErrorInfo which gathers the relevant error message data.

```
  select  @output =  ' (ERROR: ' + isnull(CAST(ERROR_NUMBER()   AS VARCHAR(10)),'(UNKNOWN ERROR)')
                  +  ','         + isnull(CAST(ERROR_SEVERITY() AS VARCHAR(10)),'(UNKNOWN SEVERITY)')
                  +  ','         + isnull(CAST(ERROR_STATE()    AS VARCHAR(10)),'(UNKOWN ERROR_STATE)')
                  +  ' Msg: '    + isnull(ERROR_MESSAGE(),                      '(UNKNOWN ERROR_MESSAGE)')
                  +  ' Line: '   + isnull(CAST(ERROR_LINE()     AS VARCHAR),    '(UNKNOWN ERROR_LINE)')
                  +  ' Proc: '   + isnull(ERROR_PROCEDURE(),                    '(UNKNOWN ERROR_PROCEDURE)')
                  + ') '
  RETURN @output
```

This data is used as part of a RAISERROR with LOG statement, then the stored procedure exits with return code -1.

The calling procedure always checks the return codes, and if it is less than 0, it will raise it's own error.

You get a cascading effect when there are several nested procedure calls, but the error message is clear about what happened, and where.

Comment: This is the same your answer in @JNK's linked question, no?

Comment: Well that's embarassing.  I didn't follow the link.  One slight difference is that this answer deals with nested procedure calls.